# VBA Put the array into the specified cell

Tags: excel, vba, xpath

I have an array obtained from xpath, I want to put it from C~**, because the number of items in the array is different, the following is the solution I wrote, but he can't execute

```
Sub main2()
Dim myURL As String
myURL = "https://exsample.com"

Set xmlDoc = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")
xmlDoc.SetProperty "SelectionLanguage", "XPath"
xmlDoc.async = False

With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
    .Open "GET", myURL, False
    .send
    xmlDoc.LoadXML .responseText
End With

Set nodeXML = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("Business_Item_Desc")
For i = 0 To nodeXML.Length - 1
    Sheet4.Range("C1:Z1").Value = nodeXML
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: So the problem is that you do not know how to set up dynamical target range? If so you could use this link: https://www.automateexcel.com/vba/output-array-to-range/ The part "Looping Through an Array and Outputting the data" should help you. Basically findo out size of the array and use it to define target range

Comment: So is your nodeXML element an arry, in that case I would go for: Sheet4.Cell(i,1).Value = nodeXML(i)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that you are trying to put a whole XML tag into a cell. "xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName" returns a collection of elements, so you need to refer to the item in the collection and to a property of the item  as follows:

```
Sheet4.Range("C1:Z1").Value = nodeXML.Item(i).Text
```

It also looks as though you are trying to write the results into different cells, so we need to correct this line to write to one cell at a time as follows:

```
Sheet4.Range("C1").Offset(0, 1).Value = nodeXML.Item(i).Text
```

I've commented out the parts of your code that fetch the document and hard-coded a document for example purposes so you can see a working example in context:

```
Sub main2()
    'Dim myURL As String
    'myURL = "https://exsample.com"
    '
    Set xmlDoc = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")
    'xmlDoc.SetProperty "SelectionLanguage", "XPath"
    'xmlDoc.async = False
    '
    'With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
    '    .Open "GET", myURL, False
    '    .send
    '    xmlDoc.LoadXML .responseText
    'End With
    
    Dim document As String
    document = "<CATALOG>"
    document = document & "  <PLANT>"
    document = document & "    <COMMON>Bloodroot</COMMON>"
    document = document & "    <Business_Item_Desc>Sanguinaria canadensis</Business_Item_Desc>"
    document = document & "    <PRICE>$2.44</PRICE>"
    document = document & "    <AVAILABILITY>031599</AVAILABILITY>"
    document = document & "  </PLANT>"
    document = document & "    <PLANT>"
    document = document & "    <COMMON>Columbine</COMMON>"
    document = document & "    <Business_Item_Desc>Aquilegia canadensis</Business_Item_Desc>"
    document = document & "    <PRICE>$9.37</PRICE>"
    document = document & "    <AVAILABILITY>030699</AVAILABILITY>"
    document = document & "  </PLANT>"
    document = document & "</CATALOG>"

    xmlDoc.LoadXML document
    
    Set nodeXML = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("Business_Item_Desc")
    For i = 0 To nodeXML.Length - 1
        Sheet4.Range("C1").Offset(0, i).Value = nodeXML.Item(i).Text
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, the code has error 424 and cannot be executed

Comment: What line has an error?

Comment: @KenYang Did you declare `xmlDoc` and `nodeXML` as **Object** (e.g. Dim xmlDoc As Object`)? ... and don't forget to force variable declarations by `Option Explicit` on top of your code module (*`Setting Require Variable Declaration`* within the VBE's Tools ► Options ► Editor property page will put the Option Explicit statement at the top of each newly created code sheet.).

Comment: @Gove I use sheet1 to run successfully, but your code only shows Aquilegia canadensis in D1, while C1 does not show Sanguinaria canadensis

Comment: @KenYang, Oops.  I had a 1 where I should have had an "i" . I have corrected it to read: Sheet4.Range("C1").Offset(0, i).Value = nodeXML.Item(i).Text

Comment: glad it helps.  Thanks for accepting the answer.  I'm curious, can you upvote it as well as accept it?  I'm just not sure.

Comment: @Gove Yes! this is what i need.

Comment: @KenYang.  My question is are you able to upvote the answer?